# Meteor linkedin accounts , redirect_uri error

Tags: meteor, linkedin-api, meteorite

I have registered application in linkedin and gave oauth2 redirect_url as `http://localhost:3000/`

Then, I have added accounts-linkedin service and added it's depenencies
 `accounts-base,accounts-oauth,linkedin`

I added loginButtons template and gave my id and secret in the fields

Now, when I try to login to the app I'm getting the following error

```
Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.
```

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: what are requestPermissions? and how did u do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use http://lvh.me:3000/_oauth/linkedin?close as your oauth redirect URL.

Comment: Note that you also need to set your meteor app running on lvh.me instead of localhost by doing:

    `meteor run --port=lvh.me:3000`

Comment: Do you mean set it in the dev console on LinkedIn? Or as a value in the template? If you mean in the template, how do you do that? I already have it set in the dev console for my app on LI.

Comment: what are requestPermissions params?

Comment: Where did the `lvh.me` come from?

Comment: Worked! But disregard Lvh.me and put in localhost:3000 or whatever your server is!